# trying to apply a single C#.NET method to multiple targets

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a C#.NET method that I need help modifying. The code for the method currently looks like this:

```
        Model1.Items.Clear();

        Color1.Items.Clear();

        Voltage1.Items.Clear();



        Model1.DataSource = modelList;

        Color1.DataSource = colorList;

        Voltage1.DataSource = voltagelist;



        Model1.DataBind();

        Color1.DataBind();

        Voltage1.DataBind();
```

Model1, Color1, and Voltage1 are all IDs of drop-down menus that get populated with options based on user input, handled elsewhere. My issue is that there can be up to fifteen separate instances of each of these menus, based on how much data the user wants to enter.

The IDs for these menus will increment (Model1, Model2 ... Color1, Color2 ... etc.) and, in the name of expediency, they will all be hard-coded into the application, not created at runtime.

Each set of these DDLs will have their own input box, so entering input into userInput5 will trigger population for Model5, Color5, and Voltage5, for example. My thinking is that I include a variable to which I could apply the number of the set, and change this method to look like "Model[number].Items.Clear();" and so on, but I don't know how to implement this.

Sorry for the low-level question, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that this can be done using user control (ascx) placed inside the itemtemplate of a repeater?

Comment: I had not thought of this, so thank you. That will save me a little time insofar as I won't have to recreate the menu several times. I'll play around with it and see if I can't make it work.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but after review I see that a Repeater isn't going to work in this case. 1. I'm not binding the repeater to a data source (no XML or SQL at play here) 2. No way to control how many times the repeater repeats (that I can see) and 3. That doesn't answer my question of how to target a specific instance of any of these drop down menus. So, I'm going to have to stick with my original plan, and question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest you one way to achieve this by using a repeater. No need to create user control for simplicity. Sorry, I code in VB so is my example below. Hopefully, you get the idea of the logic.

Here's the markup for the repeater's ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <!-- your ddl's and any other controls -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlModel" runat="server" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColor" runat="server" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVolt" runat="server" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

1. You don't need to have an actual datasource for repeater to work. You can bind the repeater to:

   ```
   Dim a As New ArrayList() From {1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n}
   Repeater1.DataSource = a
   Repeater1.DataBind()
   ```
2. You can control by setting how many items in the array (`{1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n}` where 'n' is up to number of sets to display)
3. To access any of the drop down menus from outside the repeater:

   ```
   Dim itm As RepeaterItem = Repeater1.Items(1) ' to get 2nd item in the repeater
   Dim ddlModel As DropDownList = DirectCast(itm.FindControl("ddlModel"), DropDownList)
   Dim ddlColor As DropDownList = DirectCast(itm.FindControl("ddlColor"), DropDownList)
   Dim ddlVolt As DropDownList = DirectCast(itm.FindControl("ddlVolt"), DropDownList)
   ```
4. To access from within repeater's items, same as above except the first line :

   ```
   Dim itm As RepeaterItem = sender.NamingContainer
   ```

   or, inside ItemDataBound

   ```
   Dim itm As RepeaterItem = e.Item
   ```

Comment: Maybe, you will find this usefull: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand from your question, you can create a method that accepts DropDownLists along with the sources and call this method whenever you need, passing appropriate controls:

```
public void BindDropDowns(DropDownList ddlModel, DropDownList ddlColor, DropDownList ddlVoltage,
                          List<Model> modelList, List<Color> colorList, List<Voltage> voltagelist)
{
    ddlModel.Items.Clear();
    ddlColor.Items.Clear();
    ddlVoltage.Items.Clear();

    ddlModel.DataSource = modelList;
    ddlColor.DataSource = colorList;
    ddlVoltage.DataSource = voltagelist;

    ddlModel.DataBind();
    ddlColor.DataBind();
    ddlVoltage.DataBind();
}
```